# Is it possible to permit ActiveX objects to function inside a WPF WebControl?

Tags: wpf, asp-classic, activex

I have many legacy web pages (written in ASP) that are using an ActiveX control to provide programmatic spell checking functionality (these pages programmatically validate that the user has performed at least one spell check by interrogating the ActiveX object, before allowing the user to move on).

These pages all work fine currently when accessed by the enterprise nominated browser (IE). They don't work when browsed to using another application which embeds the ASP pages inside a WPF WebControl. Specifically, I see the following at the top of the browser window:

[image]

Is it possible to get this to work? My constraints are that I cannot re-write the legacy pages into modern tech.

What I have tried:

1. Putting the site in the trusted zone.
2. Disabling a mad-scientist amount of IE FeatureControl registry entries:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_RESTRICT_ACTIVEXINSTALL]

among others. Perhaps I have missed the magic combination?

Notes:
If I right-click the page, it says it is in the trusted zone and it also says Protected Mode is Off.